# Paypal Express Checkout set Store Logo

Tags: magento-1.8, paypal, paypal-express

I am using Paypal Express Checkout payment gateway. When you checkout using express checkout, it will redirect to paypal page. On the top left I need to display my store logo instead of text.

So far I have figured out that the API used is ***[SetExpressCheckout API Operation (NVP)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)***

In this there is a field named ***HDRIMG*** which sets the logo. In **core_config_data** table this can be seen with path **paypal/style/paypal_hdrimg**. If the logo URL is set from DB then it shows the logo on paypal page, but I need to set it from

```
public function start($returnUrl, $cancelUrl)
```

located at

```
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

This can be set via the admin config section and so you do not have to set it in the code.

Simply navigate to `System->Config->Payment Methods->Paypal Express Checkout` then select the configuration button. From here you can find the setting under `Advanced Settings->Frontend experience settings`

At this point you are allowed to set the full url (recommended to be https) for the image that you want to show during paypal express checkout.